Bounded open annulus homeomorphic to the unit open ball?
In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>2$, is a bounded open annulus homeomorphic to the unit open ball?

Both sets are simply connected. That does not refute the statement.

What have you tried and what do you think the answer is?

@TedShifrin: I put in my unsuccessful thought below my question. I would say the answer is negative, but I am really not sure.

What is the reason for the downvote? If you think the answer is trivial, then say it and provide an answer.

@geetha290krm: For dimension above $2$, it is, since it is path connected and you can contract a loop within to a point --- you cannot strangle a ball.

Sorry, I thought you had $n \ge 2$.

In one case the complement has two connected components.

It would help to know what tools are at your disposal. It is easy to see that the homology group $H_{n-1}(X)$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$, which means that it is not contractible.

@GSofer: I know not algebraic topology nor homology but general topology. Would I find the relevant material to understand your proof in the Wikipedia page on homology group?

What is the reason for closing this problem? How is this not a well-posed problem?

Never. (Nor is it true with $n\le 2$.) An open annulus in $\Bbb R^n$ is homotopy equivalent to the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, and an open ball is homotopy equivalent to a point.
